# html drop down with javascript,Jquery

Tags: jquery

Am using drop down and in change of the drop down am calling
    a javascript.In the javascript am changing the content of table
    class using jquery.Now the problem is if my dropdown needs to be
    changed again,it is not all since Iam changing the content in javascript.

```
   function filterbyaptno(){
         var idno = document.getElementById("aplist").value;
         alert(idno);
          $.ajax({
           url:address ,
           type: 'POST',                    
           data:"idno="+idno,
           success:function(result) { 
               var numRecords = parseInt(result.rows.length);
               if(numRecords>0)
                {
                   var html = '';
                   for(var i = 0; i<numRecords;i++)
                   {
                     html +='<div><table class="support" width="700" cellpadding="10px;">
                      <tr bgcolor="#E8E8E8"><td width="7";>'+result.rows[i].firstname+'</td>'
                     +'<td width="350">'+result.rows[i].advicetoowners+'</td>'
                     +'<td width="7">'+result.rows[i].customdata+'</td><tr></table></div>'
                    }
                      $('.detais').replaceWith(html);//here i change the content of div
                }            
                 $(function() {
                        $('.droplist').change(function(){
                             filterbyaptno();//here i call javascript while dropdown change
                      });
                 });     

                }
           });  }
```

Can anyone suggest me what should i do to change the content accordngly to drop down values

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any of the html shown (particularly the element with class details)  At a guess, it seems that

```
html +='<div><table cla
```

should be

```
html +='<div class='details'><table cla
```

---

EDIT:

I see that you originally start out with a table that has the class details. The first time the function is triggered, it gets replaced by a div that contains a table of the class support.

So, your html will go from

```
<table class='details'>
...
...
...
</table>
```

to

```
<div>
 <table class='support'>
 ...
 ...
 ...
 </table>
</div>
```

Is that really what you want?

Comment: yes, is .details element present, first check that? @enzflep, you can be right.

Comment: hi,this is the table class details <table width="700" class="detais" cellpadding="10px;">
<tr><td></td><td></td></table>

Comment: Oh, well in that case, you're a little further off than I thought. replaceWith replaces the whole element. Since you start out with a table that has the class 'details', you should be replacing it with another table that has the class details if you wish to get the same behaviour after the first time droplist.onchange is triggered. See my answer for an update.

Comment: Try again - not sure why you didn't see it earlier. I'm replying to a comment posted 6 mins ago, I edited my answer 13 mins ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your success ajax call. It shouldn't be there.

```
$(function() {
   $('.droplist').change(function(){
      filterbyaptno();//here i call javascript while dropdown change
   });
});
```

And put it outside the function `filterbyaptno`, use `.live` instead.

```
$('.droplist').live('change', function(){
   filterbyaptno();//here i call javascript while dropdown change
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
function filterbyaptno() {
    var idno = $("#aplist").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: address,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            idno: idno
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        if (result.rows.length) {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                html += '<div><table class="support" width="700" cellpadding="10px;">';
                html += '<tr bgcolor="#E8E8E8"><td width="7";>'+result.rows[i].firstname+'</td>';
                html += '<td width="350">'+result.rows[i].advicetoowners+'</td>';
                html += '<td width="7">'+result.rows[i].customdata+'</td><tr></table></div>';
            }
            $('.detais').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
}

$(function() {    
    $(document).on('change', '.droplist', filterbyaptno);
});
```